Invalid coefficients in Quantum Process Tomography of the Hadamard gate
I am trying to perform QPT for the Hadamard operation as outlined in this document. The basis they use is $$ \{ \rho_{j} \} = \{|0\rangle \langle 0|, |1\rangle \langle 1|, |+\rangle \langle +|, |+i\rangle \langle +i|\}. \tag1$$
In the document (as well as in Nielsen Chuang) they write that we can express any $\mathcal{E}(\rho)$ as a linear combination of the basis states as $$\mathcal{E}(\rho_{j}) = \sum \limits_{k} \lambda_{jk} \rho_{k}\tag2$$ and $$\lambda_{jk}= \mathrm{tr}(\mathcal{E}(\rho_{j})^{\dagger}\rho_{k}).\tag3$$
For $\rho_{0} = |0\rangle \langle 0| $, we get $\mathcal{E}(\rho_{0}) = |+\rangle \langle +|$. Now when I compute the coefficients $\lambda_{0k}$, I get $\lambda_{00} = 0.5, \lambda_{01} = 0.5, \lambda_{02} = 1, \lambda_{03} = 0.5i$ which is clearly is not the right decomposition.
I tried it for other matrices as well, but it turned out to be incorrect. What am I doing wrong here?

The formula $(3)$ is only true when the basis $\rho_j$ is orthonormal. Indeed, to derive $(3)$, we hit both sides of $(2)$ with $\mathrm{tr}(.\rho_k)$ and use $\mathrm{tr}(\rho_j^\dagger\rho_k)=\delta_{jk}$ where $\delta_{jk}$ is the Kronecker delta. Anyway, it is straightforward to check that the basis in $(1)$ is not orthonormal.
You can instead use an orthonormal basis, such as
\begin{equation}
\{|0\rangle\langle 0|,|1\rangle\langle 1|,|0\rangle\langle 1|,|1\rangle\langle 0|\}\tag4
\end{equation}
to compute the coefficients $\lambda_{jk}$ and then, if needed, change to the original basis. Alternatively, you can find and use the dual basis of the original one, as discussed for example in this answer.

Thank you for your answer, but I would still like to know why they mentioned that specific basis both in the paper and the book. I mean, is that basis serving some other special purpose here?

They probably mentioned basis $(1)$ because, unlike $(4)$, it consists of valid density operators. Note that there is no orthonormal basis consisting of density operators, so one has to choose one or the other property. This is not a problem in practice, because you can always perform a change of basis.
